# Stmixing string with array variable to assign an id for an element in javascript

Tags: javascript

I´m trying to mix a string to assign variable(array) I don´t know what´s wrong I can not get it work.

in **php** I will send array of id to javascript via json_encode();
I will get like :**key**= 1, 2, 3 etc.
Here is aline of those div:

text

Then in **javascript** with a conditon like this:

```
$("#swas"+key).removeClass('colorme');
function xx(key, arr) {
    for (var v in arr) { //LOOP 
        var k = arr[v];
        if ($("#swas" + k) != key) {

            $("#swas" + k).addClass('colorme');
        }
    }
}
What have I done wrong ?
```

**UPDATE**
The reason I want to mix "swas" with array because in php page there´re alot of div that name
swas1, swas2, swas3, swas4.........>etc

And "key" is the id of current div that will be clicked. and "key" value : 001, 002, 003, 004 etc
What I want to do is to make the other div (that´s not the current div )to not change color.
that´s why I have to mix the word "swas" with the "key" in javascript.

**UPDATE2**
Now It work with script above but new probelm, it not remove the class when clicked :S

**UPDATE3**
Now everything just work fine after I move the   $("#swas"+key).removeClass('colorme');
To the bottom  :) S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mention swas1 swas2 etc, but then you mention arr being 001 002 etc.  These will not match.

It would be so much easier if you used jquery

```
$('#swas' + k).addClass('colorme');
```

You can use something like Firebug to ensure that your selection is correct.

If you want to use javascript then test to see if the Div already has a class before appending

```
var el = document.getElementById('hello');
if(el) {
    el.className += el.className ? ' someClass' : 'someClass';
}
```

Comment: Hei, The "swas" is not a class name. I did not want it to be a class name as well. What I wanted to do is mix "swas" with array(arr[v]) 
If one of array != key then I will add a class name "colorme" to the div.

Comment: I have updated my answer.  Also have you tried debugging it using firebug or something?

Comment: Now I get it work, but the problem is I not remove the class when clicked.

Comment: That does not really match with what your question header is.  I asked whether you had checked with Firebug.  If you had checked you would notice that the swas+k div would have been updated correctly as per my answer.

Comment: Hi  user2310289 thank for answer. Yes i accpept now it seem not match with question in the header, But the problem just happen now.

Can you please help me why it´s unable to remove the class ?

Comment: I hope somebody can help me to find out, why this can not remove the class after user click again ? very important.

Comment: Thanks, better to open a new question I think